# Best C++ STL container to store bodies in an N-body simulation?

Tags: data-structures, trees, memory-management, c++, physics

I am writing an N-body simulation in C++ that has to be able to deal with large N ($N \le 10^6$).

Everything has been going well so far, but now that I have started to code in collisions between bodies (which can result in mergers - which means that one body is added to the system and two are removed) I cannot help but wonder whether there is a more suitable data structure than the `std::vector` (which I have been using so far).

Given that each body in the system has a unique ID, I have thought of storing all bodies in an `std::map` (to allow fast lookup by ID), but, at the same time, I have to repeatedly iterate over all bodies (in direct integration methods) and consider each pairwise interaction ($n_{interactions}=\frac{N(N-1)}{2}$), for which (I believe) the `std::vector` is faster than the `std::map`.

What would be the best data structure for this, given that I have to iterate repeatedly over all bodies, but also have to be able to add and remove bodies?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning, https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nearest-neighbour.  These allow more efficient approximations if you are willing to ignore interactions between far-away pairs (because their effect will be negligible).

Comment: The title (and some of the text, e.g. "collisions¨) suggests that you are looking for a data structure for managing positions and identifying collisions. However, all answers so far discuss the problem of a data structure for fast full iteration and occasional insert/remove. Can you confirm/clarify that you are _not_ interested in the first but only in the latter? And possibly adapt the title of your question?

Comment: Your $N$ is not considered large. For their work described in [Warren, Salmon, and Becker, 1997](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1592642) the authors won a Gordon Bell prize for simulating more than 322 million bodies on a cluster.

Comment: @Kai for a little 3rd-year Physics student I think I'm doing pretty well...!

Comment: @TilmannZ thanks for your comment. Indeed, you make a good suggestion. My main issue was trying to decide upon which STL container to use based upon how I am going to be using it in my class - the other face of the coin, which you mention, concerns itself with how to group the bodies based upon their positions (in some kind of tree-like data structure) to be able to only consider nearest neighbours when identifying collisions - which my question is not directly about (although I would also have welcomed contributions on that!). I will adjust the title.

Comment: Not saying you aren't. Just pointing out where others have taken this. I should add that all these simulations _approximate_ using clever tree structures rather than lists or vectors because the latter do not scale well here.

Comment: @Kai indeed, I am also impressed with the scale other researchers have been able to take this problem to (even as far back as the 80s) - I will soon, for example, be implementing the Barnes-Hut algorithm as a force approximation technique, which should allow me to get much closer to a million bodies (I also need to make my code multithreaded). Yes, lists or vectors would not be ideal for hundreds of thousands of bodies!

Comment: [Greg Andrews' textbook](https://www2.cs.arizona.edu/~greg/mpdbook/) has some discussion on the topic of how to parallelise this.

Comment: @Kai cheers for the link! I will definitely have a detailed look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably all the accesses to the bodies that you need to perform are sequential, so a linked list would be a good candidate. (By the way, I would not delete two bodies and insert a new one, but update one and delete the other.)

Anyway, before rushing to replace the data structure, I would compare the cost of the integration step ($O(n^2)$) and that of the vector update ($O(n)$ or less) to check if it is worth the effort.

Should I add that *if order does not matter*, insertions/deletions in an array are made in constant time ?

---

Though the difference between direct and indirect accesses will be tiny, I would expect a non-vector solution to be slower.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. Indeed, I have just been running tests, and have found that the performance gained from the few possible merges (resulting in deletion and insertion) in using an `std::set` does not compensate for the loss in speed compared to the direct access of the `std::vector`. Your suggestion for not deleting both bodies is great, and I was just considering this myself: I would have to see how to deal with the position, velocity and kinetic energy history of each body (stored in `std::vector`s). Thanks again!!!

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters: I would not expect this change to yield a significant improvement for reasons explained above, but it costs you nothing.

Comment: Thank you. Based on the profiles I've run, the `std::vector` is out-performing the `std::set` by at least 25% when considering a small number of mergers (so less deletions and insertions). I would like to use an `std::set` instead, though, because it would be great to perform lookup based on a body's ID, but the difference in efficiency is enough to put me off it.

Comment: A linked list is *almost never* a good candidate, and it's not one here either.

Answer (score 2):

Why choose? You can have it both ways:

1. a vector that contains all the bodies, and,
2. a map from ID to index in that vector

Any simple modification of the vector (push_back, swap, pop_back) would also only require a simple modification of the map, and you can use these operations to remove an element from the middle of the vector by doing an unordered-remove (swap the removed element with the last element, then pop_back)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Those are all great ideas!

Answer (score 2):

With $N=10^6$ bodies, the obvious method to track their movements by having a system of simultaneous differential equations taking $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ operations per step with a rather large constant will take you ages.

There is a faster method, as far as I know, that takes $\mathcal{O}(Nlog(N))$ operations; I've only read about it, so you'll have to look it up yourself. You then design your data structures so that the implementation is as fast as possible.

Comment: Intriguing answer! Do you have a name or helpful search keyword for the n log(n) method?

Comment: The first such method is known as [Barnes-Hut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barnes%E2%80%93Hut_simulation).

Comment: @Kai hello here as well!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will be implementing soon an octree data structure to be able to deal with larger $N$ than I am currently dealing with (for the tidal disruption of a comet), and using the algorithm developed by Barnes & Hut (in 1986, I believe), as mentioned by Kai (where you subdivide space recursively into octants as you "feed" the bodies into the root cube, eventually ending up with each body in a leaf node, and then approximating the force on a body by considering the forces from bodies in a distant cell as a single mass at their centre-of-mass).

Comment: @Stef by the way, there is another method that is quoted as having a $\mathcal{O}(log(N))$ time complexity (I believe) called the Fast Multipole Method. It - essentially - comprises of a very similar procedure to the Barnes-Hut method, but then the key difference when computing forces is that the force from distant objects on a group of bodies is assumed to be approximately constant on the entire group of bodies. Thus, the force from a "source" cell can be computed on a "sink" cell (instead of on a single body like in the BH method).

Comment: Where did you get $O(\log(N))$ and for what?

To quote Andrews: "the time complexity of FMM is $O(n)$ for uniform distributions of bodies in space".

Comment: Thank you for the info!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find collision pairs for $10^6$ objects, I would suggest using a spatial data structure (as suggested by @D.W. in the comments).

For collision detection, some useful structures are [quadtrees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), [R-trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-tree) and [BVH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounding_volume_hierarchy).

For collision detection you usually want window queries (rectangular query windows) and **not** nearest neighbor queries (which technically can be used but are usually much slower).

As far as I can tell R-Trees (e.g. [Boost R-Tree](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree.html)) have the best performance for window queries, however they are quite slow to update. Quadtrees are much faster to update.

There is for example the [Point Cloud Library](https://pointclouds.org/) and [libSpatialIndex](https://libspatialindex.org/en/latest/index.html) which both provide several implementations of spatial indexes.

A special type of quadtree is the [PH-tree](https://tzaeschke.github.io/phtree-site/) for [C++](https://github.com/tzaeschke/phtree-cpp) (disclaimer: self advertisement), for a 1M point dataset it allows around 1M updates per seconds and 500K small window queries per second on my 5 year old desktop. Smaller datasets are obviously faster. For 10K points it would be 5-10M updates per second and 5M queries per second.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, and congrats on the tree-structure you have written!